# WinEdt TREE and bib files in local texmf

Tags: bibtex, winedt

I would like to be able to open bib files from other directories from the WinEdt Tree.  However, WinEdt cannot locate them (see figure below).  The project/files compile; LaTeX is set up correctly.  The only issue is I cannot click on the file in the tree to open it.

The file `le.bib` is located in my personal texmf directory structure which is added to MiKTeX.  LaTeX can find and process it with `\bibliography{le}` but the WinEdt Tree cannot locate it.

I realize I can move the file into the project directory, but I don't wish to do this.  I have common bib files that I reuse for multiple documents and don't want to duplicate them.

Ideally, I'd like to tell WinEdt a search path to look for the files.  That way I don't have to hard code paths into files.

I'm using WinEdt 11.  I've searched online and dug through the *Options Interface*, but I'm unable to find a way to get WinEdt to locate the files.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well it works for me for `\addbibresource`, and I think that this code that I added at some time is doing it. But I can't test now.

If have in my local ConfigEx/Input.in

```
//UF implemented kpsewhich search
  DIRECTIVE="\addbibresource??{??}"
    FILENAME="%[!|Exe('%b\Macros\Input\GetBibFiles.edt');Assign('UFfiletemp','%-0');Exe('%b\Macros\Ulle\UFkpsewhich.edt');|];%$('UFfiletemppath');"
    EXTENSION="*;.bib"
```

The `GetBibFiles.edt` is a standard file. The `UFkpsewhich.edt` contains this

```
// The file to search should be in  %$('UFfiletemp')
// The returned path will be in  %$('UFfiletemppath')
//First check relative to the main file:

// Assign('UFfiletemp','citeall.sty'); // nur tests

IfFileExists("%P\%$('UFfiletemp');","Assign('UFfiletemppath','%P\%$(|UFfiletemp|);');JMP('Exit')");

// then use kpsewich
WinExe("", "kpsewhich %$('UFfiletemp');", "%b", "kpsewhich ...", 10110, 0,"","%b\_findtexmf.log");
ReadFile( "%b\_findtexmf.log", 1);
SubstituteInString( "%!1", "/", "\",0,2);
//Get rid of white space to the right:
FormatString("%!2", 3, "trimright");

Assign('UFfiletemppath','%!3');
:Exit::

//Prompt("Path: %$('UFfiletemppath');");
```

Comment: This seems like maybe it is on the right track, but I couldn't get it to work.  I didn't have a `%b\ConfigEx/Input.ini` file so I added it and put the code in it.  I am assuming here `ini` was meant and not `in`?  I then added the `UFkpsewhich.edt` to `%b\Macros` but it didn't work.

Comment: If you click in the options interface on Navigation -> input directives it will open a local copy of the global Input.ini. There you can find the directive for addbibresource and adapt it.

Comment: I was able to get that fixed, but it's still not finding the file.